# preg_match in Javascript - get src from the code (non-standard html code)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use preg_match in Javascript. Please see a part of the content:

```
<tag>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum src="http://www.example.com/files/2012/11/112_156362764.jpg" lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</tag>
```

I want to get what is in **src** - so the full url. How can I do that ?

Comment: There's not alot of context here.. do you want to use regexes in javascript or ....?

Comment: While JavaScript has [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), it does *not* have `preg_match()`.

Comment: Ok, so is it possible to get what is in SRC or not ? I would like to use any possible method in Javascript, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

preg_match is [`string.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) in javascript:

```
str = '<tag>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum src="http://www.example.com/files/2012/11/112_156362764.jpg" lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</tag>'
url = str.match(/src="(.+?)"/)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've provided no context at all for what you want, all I can work with is the posted example and the very literal question, so, that said:

```
var span = document.getElementById('test'),
    text = span.firstChild.nodeValue,
    src = text.match(/"(.*)"/)[1];
console.log(src);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LWnzu/).

This retrieves anything enclosed between `"` characters, to be more specific for only `src="..."` strings, use:

```
var span = document.getElementById('test'),
    text = span.firstChild.nodeValue,
    src = text.match(/src="(.*)"/)[1];
console.log(src);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LWnzu/1/).

And the above, rewritten for a more-functional approach and, hopefully, more versatility:

```
function retrievePropertyFromString(needle, haystack) {
    if (!needle || !haystack) {
        return '';
    }
    else {
        var reg = new RegExp(needle + '="(.*)"'),
            matched = haystack.match(reg);
        // if matched is not null AND matched has a length greater than zero:
        //    - return the match
        //    - else return an empty string
        return matched !== null && matched.length > 0 ? matched[1] : '';
    }
}

console.log(retrievePropertyFromString('src',document.getElementById('test').firstChild.nodeValue));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LWnzu/2/).

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).